# Angular material table to change data based on click of next results

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

i am using angular material table, and here pagination requirement is that, initial need to show only 5 records and when click of next button, need to show rest 5 records, when click of previous 5 results, it has to come back to 0to 4 index values.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m6rnk-29ylqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.css)

TS:

```
pageChange() {
    this.dataElement.slice(0, 5);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<h2 class="pagination-style" (click)="pageChange()">Next 5 results</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slice returns a piece of the array but it doesn't affect the original array. splice changes the original array by removing, replacing, or adding values and returns the affected values

Hope this helps !

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m6rnk-7nvbsm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.css

Comment: thanks for response, i will check and update you, is it possible to show how many records are there and how many records we are showing like initial displaying 5 records of 10, when next is clicked, displaying 6 of 10 records like that

Comment: @Bhrungarajni

It Includes: 

1. **Next/Previous button Enable/disable**
2. **Showing Total & Current Record offset**

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m6rnk-ups6dn?file=src/app/table-flex-basic-example.html)

1. Next/Previous

Answer (score 0):

You can use <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html

Comment: no that is not under requirement, that paginator shouldnt b used

Answer (score 0):

Use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource |slice:0:(page+1)*pageSize">
..
</table>
```

where `page` goes from 0 to the number of pages and `pageSize` is how many element you want to show each time (in your case 5)

Comment: thanks for response, but here based on click of button, i should be able to show next set of 5 and tried this way

  nextSetResult() {
    this.page = this.page+1;
    this.pageSize = this.pageSize+10
  }

Comment: Don't change pageSize (use `5` instead of). So, when page is 0 show slice(0:5) -the 0,1,2,3 and 4-, when page is 1 show slice(0,10) -the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9-, when page is 2 show slice(0:15) -the 0,1,2,...14-, etc.

Comment: i have updated my demo, please check, here when i click on next 5 results i am getting 10 results, but i need to get from index 5 to index 10

Comment: i was able to achieve previous and next based on click of labels, but is it possible to show displaying 10 of 20 results and 11 of 20 results?

Comment: also previous and next i need to hide/show based on which index i am in

Comment: also can next results and previous results <h2> tag be moved at end of table?